# Permitir al administrador agregar productos a la orden siempre y cuando sean de la misma categoría de los productos que ya están en la orden

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

necesito poder restringir en el lado del admin la edición de pedidos.
Validar que los nuevos productos pertenezcan a la misma categoría de los productos que ya están en la orden.

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Hi Felipe, this is the Spanish version of the site. So, please translate your question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Gracias Mauricio, ya he traducido la pregunta.